# Spring boot unexpected duplicate bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

When I run spring boot I get the following error. I have replaced sensitive parts with '...' as the problem should be clear anyway. This error happened without me changing any of the code in the class that is causing the error.

> Description:
>
> The bean '...', defined in class path resource [....class], could not
>   be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in URL
>   [jar:file:/C:/m2/repository/.../0-SNAPSHOT/...-0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/...class]
>   and overriding is disabled.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting
>   spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

Comment: Do you have two classes with the same name (in different packages) that are instantiated as Spring beans?

Comment: It looks like you have a bean defined in both a configuration class (the first part of the message) and being picked up by component scanning (the second part).

Comment: @AndyWilkinson yes that was the problem, thanks